# Writing with negative numbers in sentences

Tags: grammatical-number

What is correct in writing the following:

> "Total imports in the US grew 5.82% CAGR from 2010-2012 and later declined to -1.18% CAGR from 2013-2016."

Comment: Nothing terribly wrong with what you have, though I'd tend to say "...grew at a 5.82% CAGR...".

Comment: Quibble. A series of CAGRs is discontinuous, not smooth. I've never liked seeing trending words used with a list of annualized metrics such as CAGR. I'd word it differently to stay away from *grew* (it's already in CAGR). *Declined* is also confusing. In normal usage, it implies a smooth downward trend. A series of annualized rates doesn't decline. You could use *fell* or *dropped*. Many would use *slid*, but again, its a trend word and a series of annualized rates don't slide, slip, or skid; they bounce, jump, flip-flop, etc. The rates were 5.82% and -1.18% for 2010-2012 and 2013-2016.

Comment: @HotLicks  "...grew at a 5.82% CAGR..." This has its own problems. CAGR is just one number. It is not a curve. You can't evaluate it in the middle of the reference period. So there isn't anything *to* grow. After working so hard to eliminate every last vestige of internal detail, why would you want to use words that begin to fill it back in? There is an underlying concept of simplicity to these metrics that is being lost here.

Comment: I would question "declined to -1.18%".  It's like a double negative.  It's declining at a rate of -N%? The beginning and end-points of the periods are also unclear.

Comment: **Declined to -1.18%** means that the total value of imports actually reduced to 98.82% of the value at the start of the period rather than that the growth slowed so that the value at the end of the period was 101.18% of the value at the start. Either _could_ be correct but the second seems more likely. It's like the difference between a reduction in positive inflation where price rises slow down and negative inflation where prices actually fall. Which do you mean?

Comment: Can't we use *ascended* and *descended* and recast the sentence totally as *In 2010-12 the total  imports in the US ascended to 5.82% of the CAGR  and later descended to -1.18% in 2013-2016*?

Comment: Oh, we can no doubt rewrite it.  Now that we've proofed it.  It's not hard to figure out with fair certainty what is meant.  We can probably reproduce the data if we try hard enough.

Comment: @PhilSweet -- As I understand it "CAGR" means "combined annual growth rate", or something of that nature.  To the extent that a straight line is a curve (which it is, in graph-speak), it is a "curve".

Comment: @BoldBen -- "declined to -1.18% CAGR" means that the **rate** of growth was negative during that period.  If the period was 3 years, and that rate held for the entire period (unclear in the quote), then the total decline would be approximately 3.5%.

Comment: @mahmudkoya - As the confusion of the other commentators illustrates, the main problem is that *rates* are being discussed, and hence any discussion of rising or falling (whatever term is used) has another factor involved (time) which is not made clear.  This would not be a problem if the audience is folks familiar with such terminology (and "CAGR" in particular), but is a problem for the "general public".

Comment: (Oops -- "CAGR" == "**compound** annual growth rate".)

Comment: @HotLicks Absolutely true, that'll teach me to read the question properly!